Keyboard and Pad not detected
SYSTEM: Lenovo IdeaPad Slim 3 (14AMN8)
BIOS: L1CN30WW
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy)
I am booting up this to a thumbdrive before wiping the drive out, and I can get an external keyboard and mouse to work, but not the internal one. One one hand I think it may just start working once I install and perform all updates and upgrades, but I don't want to wipe out the HD until I'm sure because it belongs to a friend of mine.
Any ideas or suggestions?

P.S.  The internal keyboard and mouse do work with a newer version of Ubuntu, I was just hoping to get it working with Jammy.
